# How do I scale something on a point

Tags: objects, vertices

I'm trying to scale something but I want a corner of it to stay still like I want to scale it from a single point/vertex.

Here is an image since I can't explain it well.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I recommend to just use cursor this way:
This is your plane with 4 vertices
[image]

Select your vert you want to use for scaling and press Shift+S to open this menu and select **Cursor to Selected**:
[image]

Now you need to change Transform pivot point to 3D cursor

[image]

Select all and press S to scale

[image]

That's it

Answer (score 5):

To add to MikoCG's answer, you can also select all your vertices, select the one you want to make active at last, in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel choose *Active Element*, scale:

[image]

Comment: I totally forgot about Active... as always

Comment: I also do  ^^ ...

Comment: i didn't forget....because i never used this :D but really nice and quick!